# isc-dhcp 4.2.5 -- does it have support of dhcp-client-identifier and vendor-class-identifier?

Tags: networking, dhcp, isc-dhcpd, dhclient

I have `isc-dhcp-4.2.5` server and client installed on two CentOS-7.4 boxes. I know this is quite old distro, but I can't change it for various reasons.

Dhcp server configuration:

```
option domain-name "mydomain.org";
option domain-name-servers ns1.mydomain.org, ns2.mydomain.org;

default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;

log-facility local7;

option space myspace;
option myspace.node-ip code 1 = ip-address;

# Tell the server to return vendor-specific information
option dhcp-parameter-request-list 43;

class "vendor-classes" {
    match option vendor-class-identifier;
}

subclass "vendor-classes" "my-vendor-class-ID" {
    vendor-option-space myspace;
    option myspace.node-ip 10.5.6.7;
}

subnet 10.0.0.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
    range 10.0.0.50 10.0.0.60;
    option routers 10.0.0.254;
}
```

Dhcp client configuration:

```
interface "veth0" {
    send dhcp-client-identifier "my-client-ID"; 
    send vendor-class-identifier "my-vendor-class-ID";
    send dhcp-lease-time 900;
}
```

I'm seeing two problems:

1. The client fails to send options `dhcp-client-identifier` and `vendor-class-identifier`, `tcpdump` does not show those
2. The server fails to send Option-43

It's almost that this version does not support `dhcp-client-identifier` and `vendor-class-identifier` at all? What am I doing wrong?

PS. Latest ISC-dhcp (ver. 4.4.2) built from https://gitlab.isc.org/isc-projects/dhcp has no these problems.

Comment: btw, trying this on a CentOS7 container (where the client version matches 4.2.5), I can capture `Vendor-Class (60), length 18: "my-vendor-class-ID"` and `Client-ID (61), length 12: hardware-type 109, 79:2d:63:6c:69:65:6e:74:2d:49:44` in the DISCOVER request. Client sent them. (there certainly has to be a specific syntax, `m` gets interpreted as hardware-type 109)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using

```
interface "veth0" {
   send dhcp-client-identifier = "my-client-ID"; 
   send vendor-class-identifier = "my-vendor-class-ID";
   send dhcp-lease-time = 900;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. You may want to add some explanation why you think this should work the way the OP desires.